# Missing Web Browser Icon

Tags: lubuntu

I installed a certain proprietary web browser only to use Flash applications (only once so far). Today, when I tried to open Firefox by clicking the Web Browser icon, it opened the other browser instead, even though I told it not to be the default. I tried to figure out how to edit the properties of the icon, but I ended up accidentally deleting it instead, and I can not find it again in the list of icons I can add. Where is it, or can I add it again?

[image: Web Browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open PCManFM, type in:

```
menu://applications/Internet
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden icons, then drag the Web Browser icon to the launch bar.